# Access VBA OpenForm Grouping and Sorting

Tags: sorting, ms-access, vba, openform

I have a form that is used for data entry. We have to go back through and add data to these records. Is there a way to pull up the form that groups the records by field "A" and sorts by field "B"? This would essentially order the forms A1-1, A1-2, etc, making adding data easier.

Right now I am using DoCmd.OpenForm to only display records with certain values in certain fields. Do I just need to modify this a bit?

Thanks for the help!

[Edit]

I would like this to load the form on button click so I have

```
Private Sub btnDataEntry_Click() 
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Data Sheet", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, , OpenArgs:="MapNumber"
End Sub
```

Then as suggested

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then 
        Main.OrderBy = Me.OpenArgs 
        Main.OrderByOn = True 
    End If 
End Sub
```

This is not working for me. If possible I would also like it to group all map numbers together and then have all Item numbers ascending. So there could be 10 entries with map number 1 and item numbers 1-10.

Comment: by not working I mean that it does not "sort" the data. What is displayed in the forms is the same no matter what I enter (sorted by the ID field)

Comment: Try with this: `DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Data Sheet", View:=acNormal, DataMode:=acFormEdit, OpenArgs:="MapNumber"`

Comment: What is `Main` in `Main.OrderBy` and `Main.OrderByOn`?

Comment: That is left over from me trying things. Main is the from that has the buttons on it. It has been switched back to Me

Comment: I added a debugging version of `Form_Load` to the answer.  Please try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenForm` doesn't include an option to specify the sort order.  However you could use its *OpenArgs* option to pass in sort information, then apply that during form load.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Me.OrderBy = Me.OpenArgs
        Me.OrderByOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Then to open *YourForm* sorted by a field named *id* in ascending order ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "YourForm", OpenArgs:="id"
```

Include `DESC` for descending order ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "YourForm", OpenArgs:="id DESC"
```

Use this version of `Form_Load` to troubleshoot why the form opens without the sorting you expect.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "Me.OpenArgs: " & Nz(Me.OpenArgs, "Null")
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Me.OrderBy = Me.OpenArgs
        Me.OrderByOn = True
    End If
    MsgBox "Me.OrderBy : '" & Me.OrderBy & "'"
    MsgBox "Me.OrderByOn: " & Me.OrderByOn
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make sense of this but I'm not quite getting there. I have added more information to my original question. More research for me! Thanks again.

Comment: Me.OpenArgs:Null Me.OrderBy: " Me.OrderByOn:False

Comment: I don't understand how that is possible with the `OpenForm` command I suggested earlier ... unless the form where you saved that `Form_Load` code ... is that a subform on another form?

Comment: All the code is on Form_Main, the other form "Data Sheet" is a separate form with no code.

Comment: Wow, I got it now. Amazing how this stuff can make me feel like such an idiot. Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, I started a comment, then saw your last response.  In my words, the code I suggested must run from the form you ask `OpenForm` to open.

Comment: Now that I have map number grouped together, can I get the item numbers to go in ascending order? Or will they just have to be jumbled?

Comment: If you're saying you want a 2-level sort, first by MapNumber and then by Item_number, use: `OpenArgs:="MapNumber, Item_number"`  That should be like sorting in a query: `ORDER BY MapNumber, Item_number`