# sql ORDER BY syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm getting a syntax error (missing operator) in my sql statement below and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditPatientFollowUpVisit", acNormal, , "ID= '" & txtID.Value & "' ORDER BY Visit", acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

It works if I remove the 'ORDER BY Visit' but I would like this in to ensure that the records appear in the correct order.

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OpenForm` method doesn't provide a way to specify the sorting. The string where you have put the `order by` is the filter condition, it can't contain anything other than the condition.

If you want to sort the data you have to do that after you have fetched it, or use a different way of fetching it.

Related: [Access VBA OpenForm Grouping and Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700366/access-vba-openform-grouping-and-sorting)

Answer (score 1):

Victoria, try the SetOrderBy method as documented here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844761(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844761%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Something like:

```
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Visit"
```